# Difference in fRead methods

Tags: c++, binary, integer, sizeof, fread

I am reviewing an old cpp program which reads data from a binary file. The code was written on Mac OS and for Mac OS. The author (who I am unable to contact) uses two variations of fread(). One with the second argument specified as sizeof(int) and one as sizeof(unsigned). Assuming that sizeof(int) == sizeof(unsinged) is there any difference in using these two methods?

```
fread(&intArr[0], sizeof (int), 1, datafile);
fread(&intArr[0], sizeof (unsigned), 1, datafile);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

specifies that the second argument is the size of bytes of each element to be read so I don't think theres should be any difference in their use-age (unless of course sizeof() is different). These two variations are mixed (seemingly randomly) throughout the file and I cannot determine why the original author would use one or the other. I just want to be sure I am not missing some tiny detail which would affect their impletmentaion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Assuming that sizeof(int) == sizeof(unsigned) is there any difference
>   in using these two methods?*

No. The `sizeof` operator will resolve *at compile time* to a value of `size_t` type (itself typically `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`) that is the number of bytes in those types (normally 4 or 8).

In fact, [this C++ Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) states that `int` and `unsigned int` ***will*** be the same size:

> **6.7.1 Fundamental Types**
>   ...
>   <sup>3</sup> For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a
>   corresponding (but different) standard unsigned integer type:
>   “unsigned char”, “unsigned short int”, “unsigned int”, “unsigned long
>   int”, and “unsigned long long int”, each of which occupies the same
>   amount of storage and has the same alignment requirements (6.6.5) as
>   the corresponding signed integer type ...

Furthermore, the use of `unsigned` on its own is equivalent to `unsigned int`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) (I can't find it in the Draft Standard, but that site is usually reliable):

> **Integer types**
>   `int` - basic integer type. The keyword `int` may be omitted
>   if any of the modifiers listed below are used.

(And `unsigned` is then listed as one of those "modifiers".)